# How to pick image from camera and retrieve it temporary at mlutiple time using sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'm new to flutter development.i want to create like below multiple add image(FAB) using camera and retrieve them temporary and delete after unwanted.
[image]

so i'm using below dependencies

```
sqflite: ^1.1.3 
path_provider: ^0.5.0+1 
image_picker : ^0.5.0+6
```

i get image from camera like below

```
Future getImage() async {
        var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source:ImageSource.camera);

        setState(() {
       _image=image;

        });
  }
```

and try to it retrieve in sqlite using code;

```
List<int> bytes = await image.readAsBytes();
```

but i cannot retrieve my previously  picked images in sqlite database temporarly..so i want to know if there any different way to retrieve images in sqlite database please let me the method used that.

Comment: If you have already the image data why would you want to retrieve it from sql? May you want to explain it better.

Comment: @ Miguel i want to  take images and CRUD them in one activity...how get images from  cache data directory  or from sqlite..please response me to solution?

Comment: I need a clear use case to understand what you are trying to achieve. If I understood clearly, you are taking a picture than displaying it. Do you want to save that picture temporarily in your cache directory? Do you have pictures saved as bytes locally with sqlite and want to show it as well? Is that it?

Comment: in my case i create incident report app..there are two activities in my app first  activity (activity A) have bottom bar with buttons set and it one button clicked open camera and after take image and preview it in second activity.(Activity B). also another open camera button in second activity(activity B) to add more images and if user can delete..that i mention above my stack question image..if user want to delete that previously load images can drop one by one..that is simple idea..how to do it please help me

Comment: @MiguelRuivo if you can help me above case.please response me thank you

Comment: I'm still unsure about what you want. You want to create a screen where the user can take pictures, thus, displaying it like in your screenshot and also have the possibility to delete it?

Comment: yes that my scope about this case.taking images and display it and after user can shown unwanted  images delete from display..its like a input text value and after show in another activity, also can delete them..in my case input values are images taken from camera or selecting gallery...how can i do that?please help me to get starting code that

Comment: @MiguelRuivo can you help to my case? please response me

Comment: Sorry I've been quite busy lately. Do you still need a hand with this?

Comment: yes I want your help